# iOS IAP Restore needs few tries

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I encounter a really awkward behavior of in app purchases in my app.
The app is a webview, so I created a webview and load my local HTML files.

Since my last update, the IAP Restore now needs several tries until it finally restores the specific product. I have 3 products and I noticed that my first IAP needs 1-2 tries until it restores, but the other 2 restore only after I try restore 3-4-5-6-7 times.

Nothing changed in restore code in the last update, and I did not find any clue anywhere in other found questions.

And a second question:
If I purchased all 3 products, should restoring one product restore all of them?

UPDATE: 
Here is my code

func restorePurchases() {

```
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.restorePurchases(atomically: true) { results in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()

        for purchase in results.restoredPurchases {
            let downloads = purchase.transaction.downloads
            if !downloads.isEmpty {
                SwiftyStoreKit.start(downloads)
            } else if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                // Deliver content from server, then:
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
            }
        }
        self.showAlert(self.alertForRestorePurchases(results))
    }
}
```

func alertForRestorePurchases(_ results: RestoreResults) -> UIAlertController {

```
    if results.restoreFailedPurchases.count > 0 {
        print("Restore Failed: \(results.restoreFailedPurchases)")
        return alertWithTitle("Restore succesful", message: "Everything was restored.")
    } else if results.restoredPurchases.count > 0 {
        print("Restore Success: \(results.restoredPurchases)")

        var isSuccess = false
        for i in 0 ..< results.restoredPurchases.count
        {
            let pId = results.restoredPurchases[0].productId
            if pId == self.currentProductId
            {
                isSuccess = true

                if(pId == appDelegate.pId1)
                {
                    UserDefaultManager.setPurchaseStatus(flag: true)
                    self.purchaseTimer.invalidate()
                }
                else if(pId == appDelegate.pId2)
                {
                    UserDefaultManager.setPicaPurchaseStatus(flag: true)
                    self.purchaseTimer.invalidate()
                }
                else if(pId == appDelegate.pId3)
                {
                    UserDefaultManager.setPicaRealPurchaseStatus(flag: true)
                    self.purchaseTimer.invalidate()
                }

                makeJsScriptCall()
                return alertWithTitle("Activated!", message: "Everything was restored!")
            }
        }

        if(!isSuccess)
        {
            return alertWithTitle("Something went wrong", message: "This is the error that I get until I try restore 3-4 times")
        }
```

func showPurchaseActionSheet() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Option", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

```
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Purchase", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        self.purchase(.nonConsumablePurchase, atomically: true)
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restore", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        self.restorePurchases()
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
    }))

    alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
}
```

Comment: I will help if you could share some (or sanitized example) of your code where you are having the issue, it will go a long way to getting feedback.

Comment: Thanks a lot, here are all my functions related with the restore. @August